# Executing python command line tools from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, command

What would be the best way to execute command line tools from nodejs to python? I'm working on a app that can generate blockchain certificates.

https://github.com/blockchain-certificates/cert-tools

This is a python based command line tool, where you can generate blockchain certificates. I have followed the steps and everything is working fine in the virtual env. But now I want to know how to implement this in to a app, where I can run the command line tools external from NodeJS. Is this possible? I have found some libraries where you can run python script from nodejs. Example I have used python shell. Whenever I run the setup script, I get missing file errors.

Can someone guide me what the best way will be to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) in node, you would go about using it somewhat like the following:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

for more documentation visit their github repository, hope i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to execute the commands using the [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function.

Make sure to only use the file once the python script has finished.

```
child_process.exec('py path/to/script.py arg1 arg2', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
  // check if generated file exists
  let fileExists = require("fs").existsSync("/path/to/generated/file");
  if (fileExists) {
    // do something with the file
  }
});
```